# How to prove $\sin(x) = x + O(x^3)$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I was doing an exercise in which I have to find the rate of convergence of

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sin h}{h} = 1$$

and the answer is $O(h^2)$. I don't understand why. The only thing I have found is that $$\sin(x) = x + O(x^3)$$ when $x$ tends to zero, and with that the exercise is solved, but how I demonstrate that fact?

Comment: How familiar are you with Taylor series?

Comment: If you find the Maclaurin Series expansion of sin, you will see that it is an infinite polynomial sum (hence the Big O notation --- look at the Wikipedia page for more on that).

Comment: In fact, you only need that $\sin$ is odd (and differentiable a few times): The given limit implies that $\sin h = h + a h^2 + O(h^3)$, and the oddness of $\sin$ implies that $a = 0$, so $\sin h = h + O(h^3)$ and thus $\frac{\sin h}{h} = 1 + O(h^2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$. The result pretty much follows straight from there.

Answer (score 5):

Start with
$\sin' = \cos
$,
$\cos' = -\sin
$,
$\sin(0) = 0$,
$\cos(0) = 1$,
and
$\sin^2+\cos^2 = 1$.

For small $t$,
$1 \ge \cos(t)
\ge 0
$
so
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\le x
$.
Therefore
$1-\cos(x)
=\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\le \int_0^x t dt 
= \frac{x^2}{2}
$
so
$\cos(x)
\ge 1-\frac{x^2}{2}
$.

Therefore
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\ge\int_0^x (1-\frac{t^2}{2})dt
=x-\frac{x^3}{6}
$.

So we already have
$x-\frac{x^3}{6}
\le \sin(x)
\le x
$.
This is actually
enough for what you want.

Doing this again,
$1-\cos(x)
=\int_0^x \sin(t) dt
\ge \int_0^x (t-\frac{t^3}{6}) dt 
= \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}
$
so
$\cos(x)
\ge 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}
$.

Doing this one more time,
$\sin(x)
=\int_0^x \cos(t)dt
\ge\int_0^x (1-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{24})dt
=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}
$.

By induction,
we can get the power series
for $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Note:
This is not original.
I first saw this in
"100 Great Problems of Elementary Mathematics"
by Heinrich Dorrie 
(less than $15 from Dover).

Get it.

Answer (score 1):

One can see this quickly using the given limit, that $\sin$ is (1) an odd function (which follows more or less immediately from the usual exponential and unit circle definitions) and is (2) twice differentiable:

The limit and the differentiability imply that
$$\sin h = h + a h^2 + O(h^3),$$
and oddness implies that $a = 0$. So, $\sin h = h + O(h^3)$ and thus $$\frac{\sin h}{h} = 1 + O(h^2) .$$

Answer (score 0):

If you know that $\cos(x)=1+O(x^2)$ and $|\tan x|>|x|$ then you know that $\sin x = \tan x \cos x = x+O(x^3)$.